# Django celery delete specific tasks

Tags: celery, django-celery

we know we have some badly formed tasks in the celery queue that are crashing our workers, is there an easy way to manually delete them?

We don't want to flush the whole thing as there might be some important emails to be sent...

Answer (score 1):

Use `celery flower` to manage and monitor the celery task.  Refer to https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/